# find degree in radian through lat long in android

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, marker

i need to calculate degree of marker in radians like 90 degree from current latitude and longitude.
Then i am able to pass that degree in marker it will use to rotate my marker in that postion.we can say car. If anyone have idea please share . thanks in advance

Comment: latitude and longitude is a position, it does not have a degree

Answer (score 0):

With the latitude  and longitude  you get a point.
If you have any more latitude  and longitude  of another point (eg your current point and an end point any), then you can draw a line between two points.
Given some reference point (eg North or third reference point) you can calculate the angle using the sine and cosine.